# How use transaction in sql alchemy while using db session?

Tags: transactions, sqlalchemy

I am using sql alchemy in my project, I used db session,

```
engine = create_engine(configuration)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                     autoflush=False,
                                     bind=engine))

Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():    
    import models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

DB session used as:

```
db_session.merge(order)      #order(model) in object
db_session.commit()
```

Now I want to insert data in to two tables order and order line item, so I need transaction,
as:
1. In first insert I want inserted order's id to use in second insert query
2. If second insert query failed then first query should be rollback

```
Try:
    #begin transaction/How to begin transaction?
    order=db_session.add(order)      #insert into order
    #is need to commit db_session here as I need inserted orders id
    #here actually db_session.commit() needed to get order's id(auto generated) 
    #if db_session committed here then sql alchemy starts new session       

    order_line_item.id = order.id
    db_session.add(order_line_item)    #insert into order line line item

    db_session.commit()
    #check transaction status if failed then rollback, How to check status?

except:
    db_session.rollback()
```

How to use trasaction?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nested transaction, as suggested by Lafada, is not intended for such situation. A `flush()` will do just fine, e.g.

```
db_session.begin()
try:
    db_session.add(order)

    db_session.flush()

    order_line_item.id = order.id
    db_session.add(order_line_item)

    db_session.commit()
except:
    db_session.rollback()
```

Or better still, if you have relationship setup properly between order and line item, you shouldn't even bother to assign id manually.

Comment: I would use `with db_session.begin():...` and, if possible, remove the `try: ... except:...` as it is hiding all exceptions.

Comment: `flush` isn't intended, too. See my answer how it should be done!

Answer (score 6):

You should use the `relationship` feature of SQLAlchemy, so you don't
have to mess around with foreign keys. So for example your order item could 
look like (I assume you have a many-one relationship):

```
class OrderLineItem(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('orders.id'))
    order = relationship('Order', backref='order_line_items')
```

And on insert you would just assign the order instance:

```
order_line_item.order = order
session.add(order)  # you even don't have to insert the item!
```

See more details in the tutorial: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to user [nested transaction](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#nesting-of-transaction-blocks) like

```
top_trans = connection.begin()
try:
    #begin transaction/How to begin transaction?
    order_trans = connection.begin()
    order=db_session.add(order)      #insert into order
    order_trans.commit()

    order_line_item.id = order.id
    order_line_trans = connection.begin()
    db_session.add(order_line_item)    #insert into order line line item

    order_line_trans.commit()
    #check transaction status if failed then rollback, How to check status?

except:
    top_trans.rollback()
```

You can also use [two phase](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html?highlight=begin_twophase#managing-transactions) transaction. Both has its advantage which one is suitable for you that you can use